# PHP - multiple file upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I am building a simple CMS for a client. They need the ability to manage employee profiles.

Each profile needs an image.

Currently I have a form for adding employees, and associating an uploaded image with a single record is easy.

Below the record add form, I have a list of existing records (and a thumbnail of the image). These records are printed between form tags, I've got a checkbox next to each record (marking it will delete it when the form submits).

I want to use this form to also UPDATE records; deletions occur first, then `$_POST` data is parsed and records updated.

When a record has no image associated with it, instead of a thumbnail, a file input tag is printed. Because there is a variable number of records, the file tags are all named `image[]` so I can easily loop through them.

Question: how do I correlate `$_FILES` data with `$_POST` data? Do I have to name each file input to `image_<?=$record_id?>` to determine which record the file belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
<input name="image[]">
```

use assocative array, for ex.:

```
<input name="image[id_<?=$record_id?>]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks good, i would add record id as index, for ex:

```
image[<?=$record_id?>];
```

You can then correlate by array index

Answer (score 0):

Using the default `fieldname[]` notation, you can't control what indexes PHP assigns to the server-side representations in POST/GET/REQUEST/FILES. PHP'll just add them sequentially and if there's a gap in your form, it'll be gone once the data hits the server.

You can, hoever, FORCE indexes, so that `fieldname[7]` and `newimage[7]` all relate to the same fieldset in your form.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to name each file input, and access it via `$FILES['unique_name']`.